# Wrong number of lifetime parameters when returning Vec of structs with reference

Tags: rust

I have a struct with a reference in it:

```
pub struct ScheduledItem<'a> {
    pub item: &'a item::Item,
    pub timeshift: i32
}
```

Now I want to write a function which return a Vec of references to this struct:

```
pub fn items_with_times<'a>(items: &Vec<ScheduledItem>) -> Vec<(u32, &'a ScheduledItem)> {
```

But what I get is an error:

```
src/scheduled_item.rs:25:74: 25:87 error: wrong number of lifetime parameters: expected 1, found 0 [E0107]
src/scheduled_item.rs:25 pub fn items_with_times<'a>(items: &Vec<ScheduledItem>) -> Vec<(u32, &'a ScheduledItem)> {
                                                                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Isn't `&'a` enough? What's wrong here?

Comment: You can try `&'a ScheduledItem<'a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your struct has a generic lifetime parameter. In Rust you need to specify all generic parameters (e.g. you can't return a `Vec`, just a `Vec<T>`). So your return type should be `Vec<(u32, ScheduledItem<'a>)>` and your argument type should be `&[ScheduledItem<'a>]`, since there's no benefit of `&Vec<T>` over `&[T]`

> Isn't `&'a` enough?

`&'a T` specifies that it's a reference with the lifetime `'a` to a `T`, meaning that the *object* it is pointing to doesn't outlive `'a`.

`T<'a>` on the other hand specifies that your `T<'a>` *type* doesn't live longer than `'a`. Which in turn means that any object of that type won't outlive `'a` and that the object cannot contain references to objects that live shorter than `'a`.